# how to select elements in array from multiple elements in another array

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, object

I have an array `A` that looks like this:

```
A = [ { "id" => "1234",     "name" => "audi",       "isCool" => false },
      { "id" => "5678",     "name" => "acura",      "isCool" => false },
      { "id" => "9101112",  "name" => "bentley",    "isCool" => true  },
      { "id" => "13141516", "name" => "rollsroyce", "isCool" => true  },
      { "id" => "17181920", "name" => "toyota",     "isCool" => true  } ]
```

and I have an array `B` that looks like this:

```
B = ["1234", "13141516”]
```

I am trying to select only elements from array A that match array A's ids with Array Bs elements.

So the returned results I would like is:

```
C = [ { "id" => "1234",     "name" => "audi",       "isCool" => false },
      { "id" => "13141516", "name" => "rollsroyce", "isCool" => true  } ]
```

Is there an easy way to go about this?

I have currently tried this but obviously not a good idea:

```
a.select {|x| x['id'] == B.first || B.last}
```

But obviously this is not dynamic, because what if I had 3 or 4 elements in array `B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A.select { |x| B.include?(x['id']) }
```